# Added new <div> element in existing modal, but it only shows on first opening of modal. How do i make it stick?

Tags: javascript

```
function createNewBoxes() {
    var flexPicker = document.querySelector("#picked")
    if(flexPicker) {
    document.querySelector(".flexibility").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="flexibility__content"><a class="flex-types"><div class="type-label">Some text</div></a></div>')
```

This is what I add to my modal. It works as I said on the first opening of the modal. But how do I get it to stick there? 
I have an ID of the element you click to open the modal, guessing I have to add something to that?

Please only pure vanilla Javascript

Comment: If the modal exists all the time, add the div into its HTML. If the modal gets cleared/emptied, you have to add it on each click/opening of the modal. Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code?